# iOS "dyld`dyld_fatal_error: -> 0x12000d088 <+0>: brk #0x3"错误 xode8

Tags: ios, xcode8

this error only occurs on i0S8 , iOS9 and iOS 10 is OK!

in simulator Error:

```
dyld_sim`dyld_fatal_error:

    0x107841000 <+0>: int3  
->  0x107841001 <+1>: nop
```

the console has inforamtion:

```
 1. dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _objc_unsafeClaimAutoreleasedReturnValue
  Referenced from: /Users/jax/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AB1A7F64-4997-4080-A44B-E3F08A568F44/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D743C101-5551-4531-B9EC-7F400C30FFE1/shipxy01.app/shipxy01
  Expected in: /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 8.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib

 2. dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_unsafeClaimAutoreleasedReturnValue
  Referenced from: /Users/jax/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AB1A7F64-4997-4080-A44B-E3F08A568F44/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/D743C101-5551-4531-B9EC-7F400C30FFE1/shipxy01.app/shipxy01
  Expected in: /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 8.1.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib"
```

in my iphone6 Error:

```
dyld`dyld_fatal_error: -> 0x1200a1088 <+0>: brk #0x3
```

console has no information

Comment: i have try : clean & build , set some frame optional, cmd+opt+shift+p, Without Any Effect。

Comment: Provide your code first

Comment: what code? when the function " didFinishLaunchingWithOptions " return YES,  the error occurs!

Comment: I remember having a similar dyld error when I ran unit tests (XCTest) on a real device, turned out you can run tests only on simulators.

Comment: Please provide your added frameworks, one of the framework may be deprecated or removed in iOS 10, try making them optional.

Comment: Also try updating your pods if available using pod update